# Why are my DIVs higher in Firefox than Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, gwt

I have a DIV in a table. This code is generated by GWT, so I don't have a lot of control over the elements that are used (which is to say that I know tables are usually not the best element for layout, but this is not something that I have direct control over).

In Firefox, a DIV with 100% height spills out below the table, while in Chrome the DIV are sized as I would expect. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this one had my pulling out my hair for a while, but it turns out that the DIVs in Firefox were defaulting to `box-sizing: content-box` setting, while in Chrome they were defaulting to the `box-sizing: border-box` setting. Because I was using padding in the DIV, this was causing Firefox to display the DIV with a height of 100% *plus* the padding.

The solution was to just specify `-moz-box-sizing: border-box` in the CSS for the div.

Comment: Please don't down vote because you don't understand how Stack Overflow works. It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/